# Error when using PrintDocument

Tags: c#, .net, printing, exception, printdialog

I have a dye sub printer, and I'm trying to send an image to print programatically.
I'm using PrintDocument and a PrintPage with C# 4.0 on Windows 7 64b.
Printing fails, and windows gives this error:

```
The print spooler failed to load a plug-in module 
C:\Windows\system32\spool\DRIVERS\x64\3\S6145UI.DLL, error code 0xc1
```

The printer works fine with Window's default Print dialog.
The code works fine when printing with a regular laser printer.
I'm completely stumped.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what was wrong with ending the post with a "thank you" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> error code 0xc1

That's ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT.  Not an uncommon error on the 64-bit version of Windows but rather a major fail whale for a printer driver.  You'll get this error when a 64-bit process tries to load a 32-bit DLL.  Or the other way around.

Clearly the driver is at fault here, you should look for an update.  A possible workaround is to force your program to run in another mode, easy to do for a managed program.  Right-click your EXE project, Properties, Build tab.  Change the Platform target setting, flipping between AnyCPU vs x86.  On VS2012 toggle the Prefer 32-bit mode checkbox.  Not actually so sure this will work, the spooler is its own subsystem.  I think there's a way to force the spooler to run in 32-bit mode for legacy printer drivers, ask about it at superuser.com